# Java and JavaScript direct communication

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications

Disclaimer: If there is a similar question, I haven't found it and I apologize.

The thing is, I am in the middle of a hackaton with an inexperienced team. I am familiar with java, but there for frontend and they work in java. The thing is - nobody knows how to connect frontend and backend of a web app which we have to build.

Is there a way to make java communicate directly with javascript, maybe through a library or java class? I am asking that because we want to design a web app only in CSS/JavaScript.

If there is no way, could we make an invisible Java Applet which would be a "medium" between java and javasript, but does not require space on the page or interfere with design in any way?

I apologize again if the question is a closed discussion, or just plain ignorant, we're note here to win, but to learn without completely disgracing ourselves :)

Comment: Learn about AJAX or Web Sockets.

Comment: Which frontend technology are you using?

Comment: html/css with javascript.

Comment: Websockets allows you to open a stream directly from JavaScript to your server. It doesn't use HTTP. It's not RESTful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would define a REST endpoint in Java, then communicate with the Java using an AJAX call from the Javascript.

Comment: well, nobody knows AJAX here and we don't have enough time to learn it... If it's impossible to make java communicate with JavaScript without a medium that uses a different syntax than those two, than never mind... but thanks, anyway.